# Sets of spells that have explicit bonuses when used together

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Some spells come in "sets" that have explicit benefits when you use them together.

For one example, the *heart of element* series in *Complete Mage*:

- *heart of air*
- *heart of earth*
- *heart of fire*
- *heart of water*

Or for another, the *primal* series in *Dragon Magic*:

- *primal hunter*
- *primal instinct*
- *primal senses*
- *primal speed*

Are there any more of these in D&D 3.5?

Comment: Is there a purpose to this beyond curiosity? I *like* answering trivia questions like this, but this list could go way long depending on how definitive you need an answer to be. That is, has the DM said, like, *Your sorcerer can take this homebrew feat to learn all spells referencing each other, but **you** must find the linked spells in published sources* or something?

Comment: No, I just think it's a neat concept and wanted to make a list for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to *Complete Mage*'s elemental-themed *heart of* spells, that book contains the revenge-themed *karmic aura*, *backlash*, and *retribution* spells and the I-don't-have-to-tell-you-how-they're-themed *unicorn blood*, *heart*, and *horn* spells.

*Complete Mage* also includes at least one spell that works better when the target's affected by another, obviously similar spell: the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *escalating enfeeblement* [necro] (*CM* 103) works particularly well on creatures already affected by the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*ray of enfeeblement*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/rayOfEnfeeblement.htm) [necro] (*PH* 269).

In addition to the aforementioned dragon-themed *primal* spells, *Dragon Magic* contains the alignment-themed *soul of anarchy*, *light*, *order*, and *shadow* spells; two complementary ones can combine for greater effect.

*Complete Champion* contains the woodsy-themed *forest child*, *eyes*, and *voice* with the first spell being better if the second and and third are already active.

*Fiendish Codex II*'s *investiture* spells grant fire resistance that explicitly stacks with the fire resistance granted by other *investiture* spells. It ain't much, but it's a thing, I guess.

Undoubtedly, I've missed some, but you can probably find others by looking for repeated first words. Authors seem to like to arrange these pretty consistently by repeating the first word so that when alphabetized such spells are conveniently located near each other.

Comment: Just be careful about repeated first words that are names: those don't follow this rule.